# Ruby String.encode still gives "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Tags: ruby, encoding

In IRB, I'm trying the following:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > foo = "\xBF".encode("utf-8", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
 => "\xBF" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > foo.match /foo/
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
from (irb):2:in `match'
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd guess that `"\xBF"` already thinks it is encoded in UTF-8 so when you call `encode`, it thinks you're trying to encode a UTF-8 string in UTF-8 and does nothing:

```
>> s = "\xBF"
=> "\xBF"
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

`\xBF` isn't valid UTF-8 so this is, of course, nonsense. But if you use the three argument form of [`encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-encode):

> **encode(dst_encoding, src_encoding [, options] ) → str**
>
> [...] The second form returns a copy of `str` transcoded from `src_encoding` to `dst_encoding`.

You can force the issue by telling `encode` to ignore what the string thinks its encoding is and treat it as binary data:

```
>> foo = s.encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
=> "�"
```

Where `s` is the `"\xBF"` that thinks it is UTF-8 from above.

You could also use [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) on `s` to force it to be binary and then use the two-argument `encode`:

```
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
>> s.force_encoding('binary')
=> "\xBF"
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
>> foo = s.encode('utf-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
=> "�"
```

Comment: @drewinglis: I like the explicitness of "binary" (which is an alias for "ascii-8bit"), "ascii" isn't exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you're only working with ascii characters you can use

```
>> "Hello \xBF World!".encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
=> "Hello � World!"
```

But what happens if we use the same approach with valid UTF8 characters that are invalid in ascii

```
>> "¡Hace \xBF mucho frío!".encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
=> "��Hace � mucho fr��o!"
```

Uh oh! We want frío to remain with the accent. Here's an option that keeps the valid UTF8 characters

```
>> "¡Hace \xBF mucho frío!".chars.select{|i| i.valid_encoding?}.join
=> "¡Hace  mucho frío!"
```

Also in Ruby 2.1 there is a new method called `scrub` that solves this problem

```
>> "¡Hace \xBF mucho frío!".scrub
=> "¡Hace � mucho frío!"
>> "¡Hace \xBF mucho frío!".scrub('')
=> "¡Hace  mucho frío!"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed if you read the source text file in using an explicit code page:

```
File.open( 'thefile.txt', 'r:iso8859-1' )
```