# Ruby `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, argument-error

I am trying to populate the movie object, but when parsing through the `u.item` file I get this error:

> `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

```
File.open("Data/u.item", "r") do |infile|
            while line = infile.gets
                line = line.split("|")
            end
end
```

The error occurs only when trying to split the lines with fancy international punctuation.

Here's a sample

> 543|Misérables, Les (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mis%E9rables%2C%20Les%20%281995%29|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0

Is there a work around??

Comment: What does `od -c` say about the line in question?

Comment: It works for me with the corpus as posted. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is probably right: you need to use a hex editor to see if you have hidden characters in your data file.

Answer (score 21):

I had to force the encoding of each line to iso-8859-1
(which is the European character set)...   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

```
a=[]
IO.foreach("u.item") {|x| a << x}
m=[]
a.each_with_index {|line,i| x=line.force_encoding("iso-8859-1").split("|"); m[i]=x}
```

Comment: You can specify what encoding Ruby should use when using `open`, e.g. `File.open 'data.txt', 'r:iso-8859-1' do ...`. See [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-new).

Answer (score 15):

Ruby is somewhat sensitive to character encoding issues. You can do a number of things that might solve your problem. For example:

1. Put an encoding comment at the top of your source file.

   ```
   # encoding: utf-8
   ```
2. Explicitly encode your line before splitting.

   ```
   line = line.encode('UTF-8').split("|")
   ```
3. Replace invalid characters, instead of raising an Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError exception.

   ```
   line.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace).split("|")
   ```

Give these suggestions a shot, and update your question if none of them work for you. Hope it helps!

Comment: The error he's getting implies the encoding already is UTF-8.

Comment: So, I inspected the each line before the program tries to split it.

It turns out that the error occurs in lines with fancy punctuations

Here is the record where the error occurred:

543|Misérables, Les (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mis%E9rables%2C%20Les%20%281995%29|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0

I tried the third option as well, didn't work out...Any ideas? or alternative ways...

Comment: This seems to address your edge case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10466273/1301972

Comment: Found a working solution from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047944/ruby-read-csv-file-as-utf-8-and-or-convert-ascii-8bit-encoding-to-utf-8/7048129#7048129