# Ruby encoding - replace invalid encoding?

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I think this piece of code replaces invalid UTF-8 characters with blank strings:

```
title = title.encode('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

What is the second argument `'binary'` for? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ruby documentation for [encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-encode) the 2nd argument is the encoding of the source string.

This may be an optional field, because there are 3 forms of this method:

```
encode(encoding [, options] ) → str
encode(dst_encoding, src_encoding [, options] ) → str
encode([options]) → str
```

You may need it, depending on what the source string looks like however:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10466273/2892779